# Implicit conversion and order of magnitude

Tags: c#

In C# standard is said:

> Conversions from int, uint, long, or ulong to float and from long or
>   ulong to double may cause a loss of precision, but will never cause a
>   loss of magnitude

can anyone explain me what does it means **magnitude**? and given
a number how I can calculate its magnitude? (i.e. to a **long** or an **int**).

Comment: try converting Long.MaxValue to float, and see for yourself...

Comment: I don't understand the down votes on this question. It's actually a great question.

Answer (score 3):

for example:

```
var a = Int64.MaxValue; // a = 9223372036854775807L

var b = (float)a; // b = 9.223372037e+18
```

a and b have the same order of magnitude, they are very close to each other, but they are not equal...

Basically long (Int64) can represent whole numbers to an exact precision within a certain range.  Floating point types sacrifice precision so they can represent numbers of a much larger range, and also fractions. So all the integral types in .net will fit into the floating points in the sense of range, but you may loos precision (digits after a certain decimal place might be incorrect. But the "scale" (order of magnitude) of the number and some of its more significant digits will be preserved...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude

Comment: This assumes the spec is referring to [the "order of magnitude"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) and not just ["magnitude"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29), which are two separate things.  It looks like the spec is talking about the latter.

Comment: @roryap Actually if you test this you will see you can lose "magnitude" but not "order of magnitude". I think the spec's language is a little imprecise.

Comment: @roryap look at the numbers in the code.... same order of magnitude, different absolute value... also calling absolute value "magnitude" is pretty rare...

Comment: For comparison, if you cast from `long` to `int` and overflow in an `unchecked` context you lose magnitude, but not precision.

Comment: @JonHanna it depends on the exact definition of precision, but yes its a nice example

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's unclear what [the spec you quoted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691282%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is referring to by "magnitude", and it's probably actually should be "order of magnitude".

Since [Dictionary.com defines "magnitude"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/magnitude)`as:

> **a number characteristic of a quantity** and forming a basis for
>   comparison with similar quantities, as length.

and [Wikipedia defines it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29) says:

> The magnitude of any number is usually called its "absolute value" or
>   "modulus", denoted by |x|.

you may conclude that the spec is saying that it's the quantity or actual value represented by the variable.  However, as others have duly pointed out here, **that is not the case**.

That fact is made obvious by running a simple test (as again others here have done):

```
long x = 8223372036854775807; // arbitrary long number
double y = x; // implicit conversion to double
long z = Convert.ToInt64(y); // convert back to int64 (a.k.a. long)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(x.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(z.ToString());
```

This produces the output:

> 8223372036854775807
>
> 8223372036854775808

So, from this, you can see that the specification, while vague and imprecise, **does not** mean the definition of "magnitude" as defined by the dictionary or Wikipedia, but more closely resembles the definition of ["order of magnitude"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude).  Specifically:

> Orders of magnitude are written in powers of 10

and

> Orders of magnitude are used to make approximate comparisons.

and

> Two numbers of the same order of magnitude have roughly the same scale.

Which comports with the C# spec in question and also to the results we've seen from tests.

Comment: @AK_ The magnitude of a number is just the absolute value of that number. 2^100 and (2^100)+1 do not have the same magnitude.

Comment: Using a dictionary definition (or Wikipedia definition) can only guess at what the C# standard intends. I do not agree with saying "thus" in the answer here. The best source is the standard itself, or the authors of the standard. Perhaps there is other information in the standard that implies what the meaning of "magnitude" must be.

Comment: Yes I do roryap. Hopefully one of these interpretations, or "order of magnitude", is actually what the C# standard means. Precise language is a difficult thing.

Comment: @roryap So then you're asserting that the C# specs are just completely wrong in that, according to you, they're asserting that these lossy conversions aren't losing any information about the value, while also explicitly saying that information is lost about the value?  You think think that the odds of you simply using the improper definition of the word (in this context) is less than the C# specs being flat wrong?

Comment: Given this: long.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807 that it's equals in e-notation to 9.22337203685E18 and float range -3.402823E+38 to 3.402823E+38 may be as "18" is inclusive into "38" this means that there is no loss of magnitude and so a statments like this float f = long.MaxValue is legal even if there is a loss in precision and in fact f contains as value 9223372000000000000 (9.223372E18)